# Merging text in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

How to locate and merge text in two columns on my spreadsheet and delete the second one?

The first one has the title Postnr and the second one has the title Postort. I want to merge the text in these columns with two spaces between the original text.

**Example**:

```
| Postnr | Postort    |
| 752 65 | Gothenburg |
```

Result after I run the code:

```
Postaddress
752 65  Gothenburg
```

My code to find and select *Postnr*

```
Dim rngPostnr As Range
Set rngPostnr = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Postnr")
Range(rngPostnr, rngPostnr.End(xlDown)).Select
```

I understand how to do it in the sheet, but I want a macro since I do this many many times a day.

I don't want to locate and mark these columns manually since my sheets have many columns.

I need a macro that locates the columns and concatenates them and removes them and make a new column with the concatenated values, preferably with the header Postaddress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you dont know where the column is located (but its in the first row).

First iteration on the first row will find you the columns, then iterate over the values per the found column numbers, build the new string and write it in column 10 (or any other column). You can add further logic per your needs, such as, when to stop iterating (when one `lastRow` is bigger than the other, etc...)

Here is the basic working code that you can expend later:

```
Sub findAndConcat()

'last column with data
lColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'find Postnr and Postort columns
For i = 1 To lColumn
    If Cells(1, i) = "Postnr" Then
        PostnrColumn = i
        'Convert from column number to column letter
        PostnrColumnName = Split(Cells(, PostnrColumn).Address, "$")(1)
    End If
    If Cells(1, i) = "Postort" Then
        PostortColumn = i
        PostortColumnName = Split(Cells(, PostortColumn).Address, "$")(1)
    End If
Next i

Dim PostnrValue As String
Dim PostortValue As String
Dim newString As String

'last row with data per column
PostnrLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, PostnrColumnName).End(xlUp).Row
PostortLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, PostortColumnName).End(xlUp).Row

'Iterating the columns rows and building the new concatinated string 
For i = 2 To PostnrLastRow
    PostnrValue = Cells(i, PostnrColumn).Value
    PostortValue = Cells(i, PostortColumn).Value
    newString = PostnrValue & "  " & PostortValue
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = newString
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: @Heresh you're welcome, please accept the answer if it solves your question (for this, and for future answers also ;) ).

Comment: I get this error 1004:
Application-defined or object defined error,
regarding line
PostnrLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, PostnrColumnName).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @Heresh you need to be in the sheet where the data is (`ActiveSheet` is used in the code), and then run the code. If you want it to run from any sheet, just define and set the sheet and use it instead of `ActiveSheet`. For now, just select the sheet with the _Postr_ and _Postort_ related columns and then run the code.

Comment: I copied the module containing the code from my personal.xlsb to the actvie worksheet but still get the same error.

Comment: Its running now without errors but I dont find the result column, Im looking for what more I have missed. :-)

Comment: ITS WORKING LIKE A CHARM! THANK YOU!

Comment: THANK YOU THIS ANSWERED MY QUESTION!

Comment: Is it possible to replace the original columns with the merged one?

Comment: Of course, just change column 10 to `PostnrColumn` or `PostortColumn` in this line: `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = newString`. As long as you dont change the original data before you read it, there is no problem at all.

Comment: But that presumes that the original columns were 5 and 6... The program has already determined where those 2 columns are and those columns to be replaced with the new one.

Comment: The Program finds the columns and sets `PostnrColumn` and `PostortColumn` variables. You can than use it to replace the data in the same `PostnrColumn` and `PostortColumn` columns.

Comment: Got it now Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that inside the sheet, then on the formula barn you should use concatanate like the following: `=CONCATENATE(A2;" ";B2)`

If you want to achieve that in vba you have to use something like the following:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ActiveCell.Value & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Where activecell (Postnr) is the first cell, and the next cell (offset 0,1|Postort) is the second part you want to concatenate and the result is inserted further down into a new column.

**Edit:** Here is the results to understand the example given:
[image]

**Edit 2:** Because you question is not clear enough I will add another way. Maybe you want to "add" the second column to the first (merge the columns into one).
You can do that using vba only.

You have to do something like that:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand how to do it in the sheet, but I want to have macro that does it since I do this many many times a day.

I also understand your vba but for this to work I need to mark the cells or does it locate the postnr and postadress columns by itself. I dont want to have to locate and mark these columns myself since this is time consuming because my sheets have many many columns. Do you understand what I mean?

I need like a macro that locates the columns and concatenates them and removes them and make a new column with the concatenated values, preferably with the header Postaddress

Comment: Please see my answer, it locates your columns by itself with no need to mark anything. Also, the text you've posted should be added as a comment to the question or to the question itself, it is not an answer and should not be posted as an answer.